# Create Groups of Gangsters / Fixers / Workers in Mob Rule

Tags: mob-rule, street-wars

I recently got a rather old game on GOG and was hoping for some advice.

So I decided to take a look at any walkthroughs online and one mentioned creating groups (Source: [Section 4.1 CREATE GROUPS](http://www.gamefaqs.com/pc/197962-mob-rule/faqs/18681)).

But how is this done within the game?  In most, modern at least, RTS games pressing Ctrl+[number] creates a group assigned to that number, but this doesn't seem to work in Mob Rule.   Is there another way to create a group?

It is rather frustrating sending in gangsters / fixers to an enemy building and then having to select them all individually and is actually making it difficult to fight the enemy families in the campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost had it right, it's ctrl+f1 and then f1 to just select a group. Love this game!

Comment: It's a great game.  I've unmarked my answer, I'll tag this as the right one when I get home.  It'll give me an excuse to play it again tonight!